# Почему "любви", но "Любови"?

Tags: склонение

Интересно, а почему, когда речь идет о чувстве, то в родительном падеже будет "любви", а когда это имя, то "Любови"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При падении редуцированных часть из них, что были не под ударением исчезло (было *сонъ-съна*, стало *сон-сна*), а часть гласных, под ударением, сохранилось. У любви и Любови, судя по всему, в дательном падеже ударение не совпадало и падение редуцированных затронуло эти слова по разному.